# Can I modify the field where using the "input" decorator in the component controller file?

Tags: angular

The code bellow is ok?
Could someone advise some articles or just advice (with description "why?") or maybe the link to docs where written why is it bad or ok?

```
@Component({...})
class ExampleComponent {
    @Input() exampleField: string[];

    updateField(values: string[]) {
        this.exampleField = [ ...this.exampleField, ...values ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Input property is basically meant to provide data from parent component to the child component.  Once you receive data in Child it can obviously edit it as per requirements. Its one way binding so this data change in child would not reflect on parent.

Comment: I'd like to know what can happen if I use this approach. Is it a good approach in "Angular" or normal or bad and why.

Comment: I'd advise not to use spread operator to join arrays and use `concat` instead. First of all, `concat` is faster. Second, `[...[1,2,3], ...'hello']` will result in `[1,2,3,'h','e','l','l','o']` and not in `[1,2,3,'hello']`.

Answer (score 0):

For me this looks ok, although it's unclear to me what you want to do.
As @user already mentioned, this is a one way binding. 
Maybe you can have a look here:

[Angular.io data binding](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#input-and-output-properties)

Comment: See, that is the problem with it. It's unclear what the developer wants to do.

Answer (score 0):

Input property is basically meant to provide data from parent component to the child component. Once you receive data in Child it can obviously edit it as per requirements. Its one way binding so this data change in child would not reflect on parent

It is a normal approach in angular. I will try to give you an example:

We have a parent component `product-list.component.ts` and it has several child components `product.component.ts`. We get the product list data in `product-list` component and pass individual product data to `product` component through input property. In product component if we want to update product data we could edit the product input property field and make an update API call.

Comment: I can save the product data in other object and update it and make API call with the new object it's clearly for me. What necessity use your approach that not so clear in my opinion. But I can be wrong. What do you think?

Comment: I understand your point. But why should we create a different object causing redundant data. This being an input property, any modifications done to it are not going to be reflected in parent component.

Comment: Also, if child component also have its own child components and this input property is further passed to it as input, it would be better to edit input property instead of creating different object.

Comment: When we do it we lost the link to the initial object. Also, junior developers could make a mistake when will see this kind of code and will decide that they can mutate the input object that could modify an object in the parent component. So, what do you think maybe better do not use this approach?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand why it would be better? (I am about your second comment in the thread)